# how to use http proxy in terminal

Tags: shell, environment-variables, http-proxy

I have to use a http proxy to access Internet. Now I'm using firefox with the http proxy to access Internet. But on terminal, I can' access Internet.

So are there ways to use http proxy on terminal so I can access Internet?
THanks!

My linux is fedora 16

I tried

```
[root@kitty wg]# http_proxy =http://proxy.polito.it:8080
bash: http_proxy: command not found...
```

Comment: Irix, HP-UX, Linux, AIX, Solaris,...?

Comment: @Jan it is fedora

Comment: Fedora 16 is EOL(End of Life). So time to upgrade!

Comment: @val0x00ff does version matter? I' just want to use proxy

Answer (score 1):

Jan's answer is good, the environment variable `http_proxy` is read by many programs, e.g. `wget`. You can add this

```
export http_proxy="http://@${proxyserver}:${port}"
```

to your `~/.bash_profile`.
Also `yum` works, but you can also [specify it](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html) in `/etc/yum.conf`.

Other programs can be configured similarly (e.g. `git` in `~/.gitconfig`, `chromium --proxy-server=host:port`).

Some programs do not read this environment variable, e.g. `svn`. You need to `proxify` them. This works by replacing shared network libraries with *proxified* versions, which route traffic through the proxy. E.g. `proxychains` or `tsocks`.

Your best source for each program is to open the manual and search for `proxy`.

*btw*, the reason your own attempt failed, was that you must not use a space between `http_proxy` and `=..`, otherwise you cannot declare that variable (bash thinks it is a command, but doesn't find a matching one in your `$PATH`.).

Answer (score 0):

Yuo need to export the following environment variables:

```
http_proxy='http://user:pass@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/'
https_proxy='http://user:pass@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/'
ftp_proxy='http://user:pass@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/'
```

Comment: how to do this? I tried something like `export http_proxy='http://user:pass@PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT/'` as command line, but it doesn't work

Comment: Just to make sure: you *did* put in your proxy user and pass, did you? Please open a new question to let us find the cause, be sure to include the actual error message or description, "it doesnt work" is no error message.

Comment: no username/passwd is needed for this proxy. ”It doesn't work“ means I still can't access Internet, for example, ping fails.